# iframe innerHTML is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

this same code was working yesterday, iframe[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML has value "success".
But, today iframe[0].contentWindow.document.body is "". I cannot find innerHTML.
Same is result of iframe[0].contentDocument.body.

**html**

```
<form id="formid" method="post" action="file/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="frame">
   <input id="" type="file" name="file" />
</form>
<iframe id="frame" name="frame" width="0px" height="0px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**js**

```
 var iframe = $('#frame');
   document.getElementById("formid").submit();
    $("#frame").ready(function(){
        $("#frame").load(function () {
        data = iframe[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
        if(data == "success"){
          successFunction(); // calling function if success
        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Are you trying to load an external resource in your iframe? In that case it might be that the browser prevents access because of security reasons.

Comment: I could access the innerHtml yesterday

Comment: You're not loading any document in the `<iframe>`. You need to specify an URL in `src` attribute. If it will be in the same domain, you can then access its `body` and `innerHTML`.

Comment: I am not loading anything in iframe. iframe is getting file upload status as success or fail.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: IE9, FF, Chrome, Safari

Comment: `iframe[0]` ? you have more than one iframe with the id #frame?

Comment: I have only one with iframe name.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you're trying to do. What is the connection between the form submit and the iframe? As written, the file upload does not interact with the iframe, the iframe does not have a source, so $("#frame").load is never called. I stripped out the form in this gist: https://gist.github.com/brainwipe/7656712

Comment: I used ajax call for file upload in FF, Chrome and safari. IE9 does not support formData, so I used iframe for uploading file. The target of form is iframe name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using different path to iframe innerHtml worked:

JS:

```
function fileUpload(form, action_url) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("id", "frame");
    iframe.setAttribute("name", "frame");
    iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");

    form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);

    iframeId = document.getElementById("frame");

    var eventHandler = function () {

        if (iframeId.detachEvent) iframeId.detachEvent("onload", eventHandler);
        else iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);

        if (iframeId.contentDocument) {
            content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
        } else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {
            content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
        } else if (iframeId.document) {
            content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
        }

        setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)', 200);
    }

    if (iframeId.addEventListener) iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);
    if (iframeId.attachEvent) iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler);

    form.setAttribute("target", "frame");
    form.setAttribute("action", action_url);
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");

    form.submit();
}
```

Html:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" name="file" /></br>
    <input type="button" value="upload" onClick="fileUpload(this.form,'url'); return false;" >
</form>
```