# iframe innerHTML visible in browser, however is null in code

Tags: c#, html, iframe, internet-explorer-8, mshtml

I'm trying to access an iframe on a website using mshtml.

- I can see the innerHTML in the website's frame in browser.
- I can also access the "DIV" within iframe from code.
- The document is properly loaded as well.
- The iframe also belongs to the same domain.

[image: I can see the innerHTML in the website's frame in browser]

However when I am looking for it in the code, it is showing null.

[image: I am looking for it in the code, it is showing null]

Can anyone help?

I tried [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212468/iframe-innerhtml-is-null), but no gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

as `doc.document.getelementbyid`

as **IE 11** has changed some accessing attributes.

[readystate is no longer supported by IE 11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534359(v=vs.85).aspx)